# assign process id to an asynchronous request tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I would like to create consistent logs so that I can compute statistics on each tornado request, I have a request as below:

```
@tornado.web.asynchronous
    def post(self):
    try:
        process_id = uuid.uuid4()
        logging.info("Incoming request (process_id: %s) to %s" % (str(process_id), self.__class__.__name__))
```

which would print some info when a request comes in, but the request gets completed in tornado code, which would only print this:

```
[I 150331 10:55:09 web:1728] 200 POST /transform (127.0.0.1) 3017.19ms
```

Is there a way to pass my process id to tornado (or make it create one), so that I can connect the first and the last log events of a request?

thanks,

Comment: could you add it to self.request?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the best way to record something like this is to attach it to the RequestHandler instance. For logging, you can override [Application.log_request](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.Application.log_request), which has access to the handler. You may need to pass either the request ID or the RequestHandler instance around to other parts of your code if you need to use this in multiple places.

It is possible but tricky to use StackContext as something like a `threading.Local` if you really need this to be pervasive, but explicitly passing it around is probably best.